# awk for different delimiters piped from xargs command

Tags: bash, awk

I run an xargs command invoking bash shell with multiple commands. I am unable to figure out how to print two columns with different delimiters.
The command is ran is below

```
cd /etc/yp
cat "$userlist" | xargs -I {} bash -c "echo -e 'For user {} \n'
grep -w {} auto_*home|sed 's/:/ /' | awk '{print \$1'\t'\$NF}'
grep -w {} passwd group netgroup |cut -f1 -d ':'|sort|uniq;echo -e '\n'"
```

the output I get is

```
For user xyz
auto_homeabc.jkl.com:/rtw2kop/xyz
group
netgroup
passwd
```

I need a tab after the auto_home(since it is a filename) like in

```
auto_home     abc.jkl.com:/rtw2kop/xyz
```

The entry from auto_home file is below

```
xyz        -rw,intr,hard,rsize=32768,wsize=32768 abc.jkl.com:/rtw2kop/xyz
```

How do I awk for the first field(auto_home) and the last field `abc.jkl.com:/rtw2kop/xyz`? As I have put a pipe from grep command to awk.'\t' isnt working in the above awk command.

Comment: Sounds like you're overcomplicating things with that many pipes. awk should be able to do the whole work from your original file. could you post it as a starting point ? (you're actual exemple has something strange with no auto_home at start, so I'm unsure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are attempting correctly, then I suggest this approach:

```
while read user; do
    echo "For user $user"
    awk     -v user="$user" '$1 == user { print FILENAME "\t" $NF }' auto_home
    awk -F: -v user="$user" '$1 == user { print FILENAME; exit }' passwd group netgroup | sort -u
done < "$userlist"
```

The basic trick is the `read` loop, which will read a line into the variable `$user` from the file named in `$userlist`; after that, it's all straightforward awk.

I took the liberty of changing the selection criteria slightly; it looked as though you wanted to select for usernames, not strings anywhere in the line. This way, only lines will be selected in which the first token is equal to the currently inspected user, and lines in which other tokens are equal to the username but not the first are discarded. I believe this to be what you want; if it is not, please comment and we can work it out.

Comment: sorry to ask, but I don't get your second awk call, this will print 'passwd', 'group' and 'netgroup' for each user and not the list of the groups for the user, am I wrong ?

Comment: That is correct. It's what OP asked for, as you can see in the sample output. He's cutting the output of `grep`, which prints the filename and a colon before the line itself in this case.

Comment: Awww, missed that, thanks. it's just to know if the user is present or not... I'm quite sure this could be achieved in one awk command... looping over a file to give it to awk still leaves me the feeling there's something wrong :)

Comment: @Wintermute:I used the while loop but still it doesn't work..You can look at my script..
`while read user; do
    echo "For user $user"
    awk -v    user="$user" '$1 == user { print FILENAME "\t" $NF }' auto_home
    awk -F: -v user="$user" '$1 == user { print FILENAME; exit }' passwd group netgroup | sort -u
done < "$userlist"`

It throws syntax error as below
For user john
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
.Please let me know any changes to be done..
userlist is a file contains the users one per line..

Comment: Anyways I got the desired the output by the below line
`cd /etc/yp ; cat "$userlist" | xargs -I {} bash -c "echo -e 'For user {} \\n' ; grep -w {} auto_*home|sed 's/:/ /' | awk '{print \$1, \"\t\", \$NF}';grep -w {} passwd group netgroup |cut -f1 -d ':'|sort -u;echo -e '\\n'"`

For user john

auto_home     abc.jkl.com:/rtw2kop/xyz
group
netgroup
passwd

Had to use \"\t\" instead of '\t'

Comment: Works for me, both with gawk and mawk, and there's really nothing in there that could generate a syntax error for awk. Hmm...what version of awk are you using? (first line of `awk --version`)

Comment: @wintermute I got the result..The problem was with the version of awk I was using..

For user john
auto_home abc.jkl.com:/rtw2kop/xyz
passwd
For user jack

[root@pacemaker:~]#awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.5

I am grateful for your help..

Answer (score 0):

In the 1st awk command, double-escape the `\t` to `\\t`.  (You may also need to double-escape the `\n`.)